# datagridview contextmenustrip : showing only for chosen rows?

Tags: c#, datagridview, contextmenustrip

I have standard datagridview and I have contextmenustrip. My problem is that I need to show this contextmenustrip when user click right mouse button but not on every row! Only on rows I've chosen.
I tried this:

```
dataGridView1.Rows[1].ContextMenuStrip = contextMenuStrip1;
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds to me like you want to open your ContextMenuStrip if your user right clicks the header of your DataGridView's column that **satisfies some condition.**

**In short:** use the DataGridView `MouseDown` event and in that event check for the conditions and if they're met call the `Show` method of your ContextMenuStrip.

Code sample that you may refer:

```
private void dataGridView1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right) {
        var ht = dataGridView1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);
        // Place your condition HERE !!!
        // Currently it allow right click on last column only
        if ((    ht.ColumnIndex == dataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1) 
             && (ht.Type == DataGridViewHitTestType.ColumnHeader)) {
            // This positions the menu at the mouse's location
            contextMenuStrip1.Show(MousePosition);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No, I want to open my ContextMenuStrip when user right clicks on a datagridview but not on an every row(cell) but only on Rows(cells) that i've chosen earlier.

Comment: Once you define your logic in the condition section of IF() statement, IT WILL WORK !

Comment: This contextMenuStrip1.Show(MousePosition); is the line I was looking for. Thanks.